# The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8, windows-server-2012, .net-4.6.2

My Asp.net application is hosted on IIS8 and OS Windows Server 2012. I have created my ASP.Net application using .Net framework 4.6.2. My application uses API provided by client using RestClient.
APP Pool using framework 4.0.
I found when Asp.net app call REST api then I got issue.

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

When I call api directly from POSTMAN it works fine even when I call my api using console app it works fine.
 Please suggest what to do for ASP.Net app so that API call can work.